# How to get byte [] from Json file with encoded base64 image

Tags: java, gson

I have a file that contains JSON structured data, and one of the attributes is a Base64 encoded image. I use a POJO to map to a Java object, and I specified the above image attribute as String type.
(tried `byte[]` but was unable to create a Java object, so I used String.)

Now I have to save this into database, using JPA Entity whose attribute type is `byte[]`.

Entity:

```java
@Lob
private byte[] profilePic;
```

DTO:

```
private String profilePic;
```

**Problem**:

```java
dto.getProfilePic().getBytes()
```

or

```java
getBytes("utf-8")
```

is changing the image and it's getting corrupted. The image is changing from something like `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB.....`

to `89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D4948445200....`

**Note:**
The contents are in a file in JSON format

Is it possible to Serialize to `byte[]` from file using any other JSON library?  The library used is Gson.

```java
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
StagingDTO[] infoArray = gson.fromJson(reader, StagingDTO[].class);
```

Or any ways to get `byte[]` from file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/orip/3635246 (instead of android.util you might have another base64en/decoder in stack;  ..e.g. java.util ;) and  ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/48399176/592355 ;) ..and when you do it correctly, it should be possible with `byte[]` (in DTO as well).

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.util.Base64.decode(). This method gets a Base64 string and returns byte[]. You should finally save the byte[].

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: Use the [Base64.Decoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html) class.

A brief working example:

```
    final String REDDOT_png  = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAIAAABLbSncAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuMTM0A1t6AAAAI0lEQVQYV23HsQkAAAjAsP7/tC7SoQhZwvDr1atXr169+gMLKP8/wbwli7QAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
    byte[] binaryContent = Base64.getDecoder().decode(REDDOT_png);
    Files.write(Paths.get("test.png"), binaryContent);
    System.err.println("Wrote file to: "+Paths.get("test.png").toAbsolutePath());
```

In your case, just swap the `REDDOT_png`in the `decode()` call to your DTO's `getProfilePic()` method and remove the other three lines.

---

**Why are you facing this problem?**

Your problem is that you're calling the `getBytes()` method on an Object of the `String` class. The `getBytes()` method actually does the following ([Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--)):

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's
> default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

As an example:

```
    byte[] test = "a".getBytes();
    System.err.println(test[0]);
```

Writes: `97` which is the `Ascii / UTF-8 / UTF-16` ... representation of "a".

But you don't want to persist the binary representation of a `base64 String` into the database, you'd actually want the decoded `base64 String`, which is just the binary content of your file.

Comment: I used byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(stagingDto.getProfilePic()); it didnt work

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? What error are you getting?

Comment: you are ignoring my requirement. It is json data, many keys and many values and in a file. So first it requires mapping to java object, to get into an attribute like REDDOT_png. Not sure why I have to decode, when I get encoded input that I want to save as-is?

Comment: Well, if you want to store a base64 encoded image, the proper entity type would be `String` and not `byte[]`. A `byte[]` indicates binary data. And the binary data of a base64 string is just some char values. So either you change the entity's type to `String` or you add a call to `new String(yourBase64ByteArray)` when creating your DTO from the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from gson to jackson api and it works

```
            try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(tempFile)){
            
//Gson gson = new Gson(); 
//List<MyDTO> qDTOs = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeReference<List<MyDTO>>(){});
 List<MyDTO> qDTOs = objectMapper.readValue(reader, new TypeReference<List<MyDTO>>(){});

My DTO has

private byte[] profilepic;
```